# How to parse thrift objects in Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, thrift

I have a c++ server which send objects to an ActiveMq broker through mqtt protocol. The classes of these objects are generate by thrift :

```
thrift -r --gen cpp:pure_enums filame.thrift
```

Thrift generates me the js classes and the typings ts files.

```
thrift -r --gen js:ts filame.thrift
```

The Angular app get the data from the broker. My problem is that I don't know how to parse the data to typescript objects.

I didn't find npm librairies for typescript that resolve my problem.
That seems to me that Apache thrift library can't help me (https://www.npmjs.com/package/thrift).

Angular & Typescript version : 6.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a complete, ready-to-use piece of code at hand, but I can provide a generic outline.

First, set up transport/protocol stack as usual, e.g.

```
var transport = new Thrift.Transport(...); 
var protocol  = new Thrift.Protocol(transport);
```

Now create an empty instance of the root object class that's serialized in the file data (you need to know what that is exactly):

```
var mydata = new Some.Thrift.DataType()
```

Read the data:

```
mydata.Read(protocol);
```

Profit!

Comment: Thanks! I have seen it but I though it can't helps me.